# Visualize several datasets as intersecting circles in python

Tags: python, dataset, visualization

I have several lists, containing user ids and I want to visualize those as intersecting circles (each circle has area equals to list length). Is there any python library that could help me with this task?

Comment: Have you looked at matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it, but didn't find appropriate solution, cause I need circles to arrange automatically, depending on intersection (I don't know center coordinates for each circle)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) to do [Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) by using [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) and then using `pyplot`, plot your circles.